# jQuery If Else If Input element output integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form which will display a value as an integer.

It will go something like this:

> How heavy is your item?
>
> 150 Grams

Then in jQuery I want it do this:

```
if (weight < 100) {
    echo £1 
} else if(weight > 100 and less than 200) {
    echo £2
} else {
    echo £3
}
```

My html is:

```
<input type="number" name="weight" id="Weight">
<p>This is <span id="Output"></span> something</p>
```

But it needs to do it live when the user types into the HTML Form. Sorry I am just learning jQuery and javascript (I am a php guy)!

I'd prefer a solution using jQuery.

Comment: What's your relevant html? Where are you stuck? As written this appears as a 'please do my work for me' question.

Comment: <input type="number" name="weight" id="Weight">
       <p>This is <span id="Output"></span> something</p>

Comment: I am stuck in the fact that I do not know how to write the jQuery if else script which processes the information in the HTML form and then outputs that live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#Weight').on('keyup', function () {
    var price = '£3';

    if (this.value < 100) {
        price = '£1';
    } else if (this.value >= 100 && this.value < 200) {
        price = '£2';
    }

    $('#Output').html(price);
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/TYXMr/

Comment: This is fantastic Joe that works great! One more thing.. if I wanted to add a checkox as well eg 'Do you want next day delivery? YES / NO' how could I add this into the is else statement?